# Migrating Data From Amazon Redshift into DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

There are tons of examples to migrate data from DynamoDB to Redshift, but I couldn't find any example or documentation for migrating data from Redshift to DynamoDB. Any suggestion/example/doc for migrating data from Redshift into DynamoDB in an efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution which includes writing some code is to use RedShift's
[unload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) feature and put the query data into an s3 bucket. By doing so you can handle the Put Event for this specific bucket and either trigger a lambda function that persists data to dynamodb, or send an sqs message to a beanstalk worker which does the same action (persisting data to dynamodb)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can migrate from Redshift to DynamoDB

You can unload the data from redshift using "UNLOAD" and save the files to s3. From s3 you can use multiple services to migrate the data.

- You can use aws pipeline to read data from s3 and load into dynamo
- You can use AWS Glue to read data into its dataframe and load into dynamo -> an approach i prefer
- You can use s3 import

But you unload from redshift as a redshift json you need to convert into dynamo Json and then load into the DB